# What is earliest known usage of 불교의 만자 in Korea?

Tags: spoken-korean, korean-culture, history-of-korean

There are many Buddhist temples with the usage of 불교의 만자, but I can't find any informaiton about where the oldest symbol is.
The book by Thomas Wilson addresses the history (pre-history) but does not specifically address Korean history of this.

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/40812/40812-h/40812-h.htm

Answer (score 1):

Do you want temples or literature?

According to this page, there are many swastikas in Goryeo Dynasty Buddhist paintings.

http://www.ibulgyo.com/news/articleView.html?idxno=66000

And this painting is from the 14th century. https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%95%84%EB%AF%B8%ED%83%80%EC%82%BC%EC%A1%B4%EB%8F%84_(%EA%B5%AD%EB%B3%B4_%EC%A0%9C218%ED%98%B8)